# querystring function failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

I'm using the following function to enable me to easily grab querystrings from URL's.

```
var urlParams = {};
(function () {
var e,
    a = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
    r = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
    d = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(a, " ")); },
    q = window.location.search.substring(1);

while (e = r.exec(q))
   urlParams[d(e[1])] = d(e[2]);
})();
```

Then I simply call

```
var k=urlParams["url"];
var ttl=urlParams["title"];
```

This has been working great, except for the following querystring which breaks the function:

`?title=Jpreay%20will%20do%20a%20press%20release%20or%20news%20announcement%20commercial%20for%20$5,%20only%20on%20fiverr.com&cnt=For%20only%205$,%20jpreay%20will%20do%20a%20press%20release%20or%20news%20announcement%20commercial.%20Top%20Rated%20Seller%20100%%20Rating%20for%20Over%2010%20Months%20Now%20In%20this%20gig%20I%20am%20providing%20a%20news%20release%20or%20some%20other%20type%20of%20event%20|%20On%20Fiverr.com&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffiverr.com%2Fjpreay%2Ffilm-a-press-release-or-news-announcement-of-your-product-or-services`

I get the following error:

```
URIError: malformed URI sequence
[Break On This Error]   
var k=urlParams["url"];
```

Can anyone help me figure out what the problem here is?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use unescape, and include the ? in the matching regex instead of doing a substring. I'd also move the space replace outside of the unescape, just in case the function doesn't like spaces.

So, we end up with:

```
var urlParams = {};
(function () {
var e,
    a = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
    r = /([^&?=]+)=?([^&?]*)/g,
    d = function (s) { return unescape(s).replace(a, " "); },
    q = window.location.search;

while (e = r.exec(q))
   urlParams[d(e[1])] = d(e[2]);
})();
```

When I test (using your string in place of window.location.search),

```
var k=urlParams["url"];
var ttl=urlParams["title"];
console.log('k='+k);
console.log('ttl='+ttl);
```

I get this:

```
k=http://fiverr.com/jpreay/film-a-press-release-or-news-announcement-of-your-product-or-services
ttl=Jpreay will do a press release or news announcement commercial for $5, only on fiverr.com
```